# Why isnt't the PNG's transparency displayed correctly?

Tags: go, opengl, graphics, png, sdl-2

I'm using the Go bindings for SDL and OpenGL.
This is how I load the texture:

```
func (sprite *Sprite) loadImage(name string) {
    surf, err := img.Load(name)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    sprite.width = surf.W
    sprite.height = surf.H

    gl.Enable(gl.TEXTURE_2D)
    gl.GenTextures(1, &sprite.tex)
    gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, sprite.tex)
    gl.TexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA8, surf.W, surf.H, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, surf.Data())
    gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0)

    gl.GenFramebuffers(1, &sprite.framebuffer)
    gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, sprite.framebuffer)
    gl.FramebufferTexture2D(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, sprite.tex, 0)
    gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
}
```

I draw it using:

```
func (sprite *Sprite) draw() {
    gl.Enable(gl.BLEND)
    gl.BlendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

    gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, sprite.framebuffer)
    gl.BlitFramebuffer(0, 0, int32(sprite.width), int32(sprite.height), 0, 0, 100, 100, gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, gl.LINEAR)
    gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)

    gl.Disable(gl.BLEND)
}
```

Draw Loop:

```
for running {
    for event := sdl.PollEvent(); event != nil; event = sdl.PollEvent() {
        switch event.(type) {
        case *sdl.QuitEvent:
            running = false
            break
        }
    }
    gl.ClearColor(0.3, 1.0, 0.3, 1.0)
    gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    sp.draw()

    window.GLSwap()
}
```

It works correctly, however the Alpha-Channel doesn't seem to be considered by OpenGL. The textures' transparent parts a being drawn as black:

[image: Black Transparency]

**So how can I make the transparency work?**

Comment: `BlitFramebuffer` is a copy operation. [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) only applies to drawing operations.

Comment: Which function would I use instead?

Comment: You have to draw a rectangular shape and wrap the texture on it.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help, I will try it out!